# Reading columns as lists

Tags: python, csv

I have data in a txt file in the form. Tab-delimited data

```
here
     a b c
     e f g
tere
     x y z
     w t y
```

I need to read the columns into lists. like

```
col1 = ['here', '', '', tere, '', '']
col2= ['', 'a', 'e', '', 'x'.'w']
```

and so on.

I have used

```
import re

infile = open('text.txt', 'r')
i=0
a0='';a1='';a2='';a3='';a4='';a5='';a6='';a7='';
for line in infile:
    [a1[i],a2[i],a3[i],a4[i],a5[i],a6[i],a7[i],a8[i]] = line.split('\t')
    i+=1
```

It says 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction to @Martijn Pieters answer

It should have been like this

```
per_row = []
for line in infile:
    per_row.append(line.split('\t'))
```

And only then turn that into a list of columns:

```
per_column = zip(*per_row)
```

This is now a list of lists; `per_column[0]` is the first column of data.

This gives the result i want. `strip()` removes blank cells also.

Comment: You should keep strip in place, but use it in a way that fits your data so that it correctly removes newline characters. Consider .rstrip('\n') to only remove newline characters on the right side of the line.

Answer (score 6):

If you want all the data assigned to variables *per column*, start with a list:

```
per_row = []
for line in infile:
    per_row.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
```

And only then turn that into a list of *columns*:

```
per_column = zip(*per_row)
```

This is now a list of lists; `per_column[0]` is the first column of data.

You really want to use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead to read tabular data though.

Your code, unfortunately, is not nearly close enough to working Python. You assigned several variables the empty string, then tried to use them as lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
a0='';a1='';a2='';a3='';a4='';a5='';a6='';a7='';
```

once you have declared variables to empty strings, you can't change the string individually (character-by-character) because they are immutable strings.

```
[a1[i],a2[i],a3[i],a4[i],a5[i],a6[i],a7[i],a8[i]] = line.split('\t')
```

So, you can use lists of strings instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module is often also the best way to handle tab-delimited files:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import csv

MAXCOLS = 4
cols = [[] for _ in xrange(MAXCOLS)]
with open('text.txt', 'rb') as input:
    for row in csv.reader(input, delimiter='\t'):
        for i in xrange(MAXCOLS):
            cols[i].append(row[i] if i < len(row) else '')

for i in xrange(MAXCOLS):
    print('cols[{}]: {}'.format(i, cols[i]))
```

Output:

```
cols[0]: ['here', '', '', 'tere', '', '']
cols[1]: ['', 'a', 'e', '', 'x', 'w']
cols[2]: ['', 'b', 'f', '', 'y', 't']
cols[3]: ['', 'c', 'g', '', 'z', 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

## open file
infile = open('col2Rows.txt', 'r')

## define csv reader object, assuming delimiter is tab
tsvfile = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')

lines = []

## iterate through lines in file
for line in tsvfile:
    lines.append(line)

print "Col1",[line[0] for line in lines]
```

Like Martijn Pieters said, the csv module is pretty handy. Just make sure you dont run out of memory (i.e the input file should nt be too large.)